# How to fix "the bad layout in QWizardPage"

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm build a QWizard. There are several widgets in the QWizardPage. So I put all the widgets in a scroll area. But it broke up the layout of the QWizardPage.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import simplewizard_rc

class SimpleWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleWizard, self).__init__(parent)
        self.addPage(Page1(self))
        self.addPage(Page2(self))
        self.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.ModernStyle)
        self.setPixmap(QtWidgets.QWizard.LogoPixmap, QtGui.QPixmap(":/image/logo.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Wizard Example")

class Page1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle(self.tr("Hello"))
        self.setPixmap(QtWidgets.QWizard.WatermarkPixmap, QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/watermark.png"))

    def initializePage(self):
        scrolllayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        scrollwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollwidget.setLayout(scrolllayout)

        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(scrollwidget)

        for i in range(8):
            grouptext = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
            scrolllayout.addWidget(grouptext)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label1")
        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label2")
        label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label3")

        hLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        hLayout.addWidget(label1)
        hLayout.addWidget(label2)
        hLayout.addWidget(label3)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(scroll)
        layout.addLayout(hLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Page2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def initializePage(self):
        self.label1.setText("Example text")
        self.label2.setText("Example text")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wizard = SimpleWizard()
    wizard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code works, but the height of widget has a bigger height than usual. What is the problem in my code? 
If the QScrollArea control contains only one QTextEdit control, then the entire layout is no problem. 
[One QTextEdit in the QScrollArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLU7c.png)
However, if the QScrollArea contains three QTextEdit controls, then some white space will appear below the image.
[8 QTextEdit in the QScrollArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PndZU.png)
The effect I want is that when QScroolArea contains multiple QTextEdits, there will be no blank areas below the image on the left.

Comment: Your code doesn't run, could you fix it so we can try it?

Comment: the simplewizard_rc.py is the resource file. How can I upload that resource file? There are another fault in the file, I have fix it.

Comment: I removed both lines so the code compiled but the program freezes when I run it, that's why I posted a comment.

Comment: @RayYang I do not understand you, at what height do you mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added two figures to describe the effects.